# can't join a server to a domain using powershell direct

Tags: powershell, active-directory, hyper-v, windows-server

i want to automate adding server to lab environment, i had problem when i tryed to join a server to a domain using power-shell **direct** :

```
Enter-PSSession -VMName S2D2 -Credential $cred
Add-Computer -DomainName "yp.org" -Credential  yp.org\administrator
```

give me this error :

```
Add-Computer : Computer 'WIN-ORGQD2DH4PU' failed to join domain 'yp.org' from its current workgroup 'WORKGROUP' with 
following error message: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (WIN-ORGQD2DH4PU:String) [Add-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToJoinDomainFromWorkgroup,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddComputerCommand
```

ps: dns is working :

```
    ping -n 2 ADDC  

Pinging ADDC [192.168.3.10] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.3.10: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.3.10: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

Comment: You cannot automate `Enter-PSSession` because it creates a new interactive session. Use `New-PSSession` and call it by doing `Invoke-Command -Session $YourPSSession -Credential $credentials -Scriptblock {Add-Computer -ComputerName "YourComputerName" -DomainName "yp.org"}` This way will allow you to automate that process

Comment: @coryEtmund but before write the automate script you have to try command with Enter-PSSession

Comment: That is incorrect. You can do exactly what I stated in my first comment in a PowerShell console and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem is that i have two DNS domain in my environment i type the false ip DNS server. now it's work

Answer (score 1):

[This demo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/blob/78d91946bcbf5a86513be10c6fd643965a3c71f8/demos/2015-Ignite-Whats-New/scripts/WorkloadSetup.ps1#L92-L93) from Ignite 2015 implies that you should wait for DNS.

```
while (!(Test-Connection -Computername <# DNS IP address #> -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -Quiet -ea SilentlyContinue)) {sleep -seconds 1}
Add-Computer
```

Here I try to rewrite that code for generic use.

```
$VMName = "Old Virtual Machine"
$localCred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
             -argumentlist "Administrator", (ConvertTo-SecureString "P@ssw0rd" -AsPlainText -Force)
$domainCred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
              -argumentlist "Ignite\Administrator", (ConvertTo-SecureString "P@ssw0rd" -AsPlainText -Force)
$DnsIpAddress = "10.100.7.1"
$DomainName = "Ignite.demo"


Invoke-Command -VMName $VMName -Credential $localCred -ScriptBlock {
         param($VMName, $domainCred, $DnsIpAddress, $DomainName)
         Write-Output "[$($VMName)]:: Joining domain as `"$($env:computername)`""
         while (!(Test-Connection -Computername $DnsIpAddress -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -Quiet -ea SilentlyContinue)) {sleep -seconds 1}
         Add-Computer -DomainName $DomainName -Credential $domainCred
         } -ArgumentList $VMName, $domainCred, $DnsIpAddress, $DomainName
}
```

It looks like $localCred is the local administrator on the virtual machine (who you would log in as).

And $domainCred is someone who can add a computer to the domain.

You might also find [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/powershell-direct) useful.

Credit belongs to Sarah Cooley for the original code.

### DNS Troubleshooting

You can see what DNS servers are being used with [this code](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7184ec22-acfd-4b42-8838-82c59150cdba/output-all-servers-listed-under-dns-servers-across-all-servers-in-a-domain?forum=ITCG):

```
$net = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName localhost -Filter 'IPEnabled=True'

$props = @{
    DNSHostName = $net.DNSHostName
    DNSServerSearchOrder = $net.DNSServerSearchOrder -join ','
    Description = $net.Description
    IPAddress = $net.IPAddress -join ','
}

New-Object PsObject -Property $props | format-list
```

And you can learn more about the virtual machine's DNS environment with [nslookup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940085.aspx) or [dig](https://help.dyn.com/how-to-use-binds-dig-tool/).

If you want to ask a new question about a DNS issue, you can try [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: but its not a DNS problem see the ps on my question  ping -n 2 ADDC